# Refresh plugin in nuxt config transition hooks

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

How to get to the plugin from nuxt.config.js? 
where "console.log('afterEnter');" I want to do "AOS.refresh();"

```
    { src: '~/plugins/aos.js', ssr: false }
  ],
  transition: {
    afterEnter: function () {
       console.log('afterEnter');
    }
  },

//File aos.js

import Vue from 'vue'

import AOS from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";

Vue.use(AOS.init({
  // Global settings:
}));
```